# iptables subdomain port forward

Tags: networking, iptables, domain

Hello i know i can setup iptables to forward to an other ip when a port is given

Example:

- user enters domain.com and it shows site
- other user types domain.com:28015 and it connects to a game server

now can i do make so it will only work on a subdomain?

for example

- user enter sub.domain.com and it shows the site of the subdomain
- user enters sub.domain.com:28015 and it connects to the game server

the reason i want this is because i have a couple of game servers and all the have a site running on there own subdomain (ex rust.domain.com and mc.domain.com).

so is it posible to do this so users can connect to a game server when using the subdomain and port.

Comment: DNS has nothing to do with ports. Dns for sub.domain.com will point to 1 IP address. On that IP you should have running both the webserver and gameserver - or redirect one of those via `iptables` to other IP.

Comment: yes i know but is it posible to make it so it only will work on that subdomain ? and not the whole domain

Comment: No - iptables work only with IPs. To make it work, you need to assign different IP to domain.com and different IP to sub.domain.com

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. TCP packets have only source and destination IP addresses in them, not FQDN. So if your domain and subdomain both point to the same IP addresses, there's no way iptables can distinguish which 'domain' user is connecting to.

Comment: ok hear me out on this one i made a sub domain pointing to my dedicated server running windows 2008 if i set up a iptable on that server for port 80 to the webserver wil it work ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution

so i made the subdomain and gave it the ip of the dedicate server where my game servers is hosted.

the i logged in on the server running windows 2008 and used netsh interface portproxy to redirect all port 80 requests to the web server